# Hide rows in cross-tab for FastReport

Tags: delphi, pascal, fastreport

I've been trying to hide rows from a cross-tab in FastReport, but i can't find the way to do it.

When i hide the MemoViews, it leaves me a blank space and i don't know how to get rid of it.

Here's the code:

```
procedure DBCross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin
       if (cellindex = 1) and (rowindex = 1) then begin
               memo.visible := false;
               memo.height  := 0;    
       end;                                  
end;

procedure DBCross1OnPrintRowHeader(Memo: TfrxMemoView; HeaderIndexes, HeaderValues, Value: Variant);
begin                                           
  if (trim(memo.memo.text) = 'HORA') and ( HeaderIndexes[0] = 1 ) then begin              
       memo.visible:=false;
       memo.height  := 0;           
  end;                                  
  if (trim(memo.memo.text) = 'individual') then begin
       memo.height  := memo.height /2;               
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use event OnCalcHeight on DBCross

Comment: I've tried, but it doesn't let me put a Height lower than the original

Comment: In my version (Fast Report 4) it works. Otherwise try to set default height on 0 and then set for all other rows to the height you prefer.

Comment: Still nothing.
Maybe this image could help you understand my problem http://twitpic.com/cyx4hc

Comment: I understand your problem, I tried to simulate, but in my case it works. Row is not visible.

Comment: procedure DBCross1OnCalcHeight(RowIndex: Integer; RowValues: Variant; var Height: Extended);
begin
  if RowIndex = 1 then
    Height:=0;              
end;

Answer (score 0):

I have found just one way to solve this problem. You have to disable autosize in crosstab and manage the size and position of cells from script in same procedures you already got.

Something like this

*

```
*procedure DBCross1OnPrintCell(Memo: TfrxMemoView; RowIndex, ColumnIndex, CellIndex: Integer; RowValues, ColumnValues, Value: Variant);
begin

if (checkbox1.checked = false) and (cellindex = 0) then begin
memo.width := 0;    
memo.visible := false;
memo.printable := false;          
end; if (checkbox1.checked = false) and (cellindex <> 0) then begin
memo.left := memo.left - ((columnindex+1)*100);
end;
end;
procedure DBCross1OnPrintColumnHeader(Memo: TfrxMemoView; HeaderIndexes, HeaderValues, Value: Variant);
begin

if (checkbox1.checked = false) and (trim(memo.memo.text) = 'Первичные пациенты') then begin
memo.width := 0; memo.text := '';memo.visible := false;memo.printable := false; end;          

if (checkbox1.checked = false) and (HeaderIndexes[0] >= 0) and (memo.width > 100) then begin
memo.width := memo.width - 100; end;    

end;
end;*
```

*